# AddCircleIcon material ui disabled not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

The disabled functionality of the AddCircleIcon button not working, but the onClick function works properly. Also if I directly pass true to the disabled property, still it doesn't work. I need help in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

The fields tag is a custom input tag.

**AddCircleIcon is of Material UI=>**

```
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';

const [moreLinks, updateMore] = useState([]);

const addMore = () => {
  updateMore([{name: 'more data', value: ''}]);
};

const disableAddMore = React.useMemo(() => {
 return moreLinks.length >= 1;
}, [moreLinks]);

<Fields
  name='moreDate'
  center={true}
  register={register}
  extraComponent={
    <AddCircleIcon
       onClick={addMore}
       disabled={disableAddMore}
       className={classes.addIcon}
    />
  }
/>
```

**This example also doesn't work**

```
<Fields
  name='moreDate'
  center={true}
  register={register}
  extraComponent={
    <AddCircleIcon
       onClick={addMore}
       disabled={true}
       className={classes.addIcon}
    />
  }
/>
```

Comment: This is a copy/paste of your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68689934/addcircleicon-material-ui-disabled-not-working), with the addition of "The fields tag is a custom input tag.". Please don't delete and ask the same question, this could be considered queue jumping.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the [icon docs](https://material-ui.com/api/icon/) you'll see that they don't directly consume an `onClick` or `disabled` prop, but they extend the root `native element`, so this is why the `onClick` handler still works.

I believe you want to wrap the icon with a button in order to make the `disabled` prop work. There exists an [IconButton](https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/) that extends the [BaseButton](https://material-ui.com/api/button-base/).

```
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import AddCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddCircle';

...

const [moreLinks, updateMore] = useState([]);

const addMore = () => {
  updateMore([{name: 'more data', value: ''}]);
};

const disableAddMore = React.useMemo(() => {
 return moreLinks.length >= 1;
}, [moreLinks]);

<Fields
  name='moreDate'
  center={true}
  register={register}
  extraComponent={
    <IconButton
      onClick={addMore}
      disabled={disableAddMore}
    >
      <AddCircleIcon className={classes.addIcon} />
    </IconButton>
  }
/>
```

[image: Edit addcircleicon-material-ui-disabled-not-working]